# MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig in NService Bus 3 beta

Tags: nservicebus

I'm currently in the process of migrating an application that uses NServiceBus 2.6 to the latest beta of NServiceBus 3. But I can't get it to start. In the web.config the following line causes an error:

```
<MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="myApp_subscriptions"/>
```

The error:

```
Parser Error Message: The value of the property 'Queue' cannot be parsed. The error is: Unable to find a converter that supports conversion to/from string for the property 'Queue' of type 'Address'.
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? It was working fine in the 2.6 release.

Comment: That looks like a bug, I'll investigate and get back to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug (https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/182) in the current beta. It will be fixed in beta7 that will be out in a few days. A temporary workaround is to remove the config entry and move the subscriptions to the new queue that gets created using a script/queue explorer